# list of all mac address i've connected to in the past

Tags: wireless

i need your help please !

i'd like to know if it's possible to see a kind of history list of all Mac address i've scanned or attempted to pentest before.

i once tried to crack my galaxy s5 access point password and now is it possible to retrieve the mac address ?

thank you in advance for your replies...

Comment: It's not possible. You can view your arp cache by issuing `arp` command. But entries in the cache live shortly and afterwards are definitely lost, if not refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever access point you connect to with Network Manager , will have a settings file in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` folder. For instance:

```
$ sudo grep -i 'mac' /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Jes                             
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 
mac-address=**:**:**:**:**:** # obfuscated for reasons
```

If you were using something other than Network Manager - bad news, it's not possible to recover that information

Comment: thank you all. i was working in the terminal. but i remember that i did connected to it through a wifi adapter.

Comment: Glad to help. Please leave upvote if the answer helped you , and if it solves the question you asked - mark it as accepted